# What Can I Do If My Joint Operations App/Game Is Rejected Because the HMS Core (APK) Update Pop-up Cannot Be Closed?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery

I have submitted a game for review is rejected because the HMS Core (APK) update pop-up displays repeatedly. The mainly error  log is :
E/HMSSDK_X509CertUtil(11044): Not include alias 052root
E/HMSSDK_X509CertUtil(11044): rootCert is null,verify failed
E/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager(11044): failed to verify cert chain
E/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager(11044): checkSinger failed
E/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager(11044): Failed to find HMS apk
I/HMSSDK_AvailableAdapter(11044): HMS is not installed
what does it means?

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that the hmsrootcas.bks certificate file is missing, which leads to the update failure of HMS Core (APK).

[image]

If you use the Maven repository to integrate the HMS Core SDK in Android Studio, the certificate file is automatically stored in the **assets** directory of the APK.

But if you directly download the SDK and integrate it into an Eclipse project, the file may be missing due to incorrect or missing operations. You can download and import the certificate file again by referring to the following document:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/appgallerykit-eclipse-0000001055855915?ha_source=hms1